# Notifications not showing

Tags: java, android

im trying to send notification to phone, but it doesnt send

**imports:**

```
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
```

**my code:**

```
public void sendNotification(){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NotificationChannel.DEFAULT_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Content");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Why isn't it showing? 
Is intent needed?
What should the channel be?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a service?

Comment: @VinceVD I don't think i use any services. Don't know what that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you are using a Service**

**Starting in Android 8.0 (API level 26), all notifications must be assigned to a channel.**

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 100);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel =
                new NotificationChannel(
                        100,
                        "Media PlayBack",
                        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManager != null) {
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
 }

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent =  PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
.setContentTitle("Title")
.setContentText("Content")
.setContentIntent(contentIntent); 

Notification notification = builder.build();
startForeground(101, notification);
```

Comment: What is a service? I think i dont use any. This code brings errors with arguments in Builder and NotificationChannel. And startForeground doesnt exist for me.

Comment: @TomiKordos Then you're not using a Service too manage your notification, what purpose does your notification have?

Comment: i want to notify users 24 hours after last action... I tried installing firebase, but i got new error ive never had. It says Error type 3, Activity class does not exist

Comment: What should i post? It keeps spamming errors like Package com.android.camera is not encryption aware! so its hard to find other errors... Im using my real device

Comment: @TomiKordos Can you upload it to github so i can take a look myself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206167/discussion-between-vince-vd-and-tomi-kordos).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using firebase to send notifications you need a firebase messaging service activity to receive the notifications. and add the data to your manifest file to receive notifications.

Comment: Give me sometime to browse for videos that clearly helps you.

Comment: I don't use firebase, havent tried anything with it, so i have no idea what it is.

Comment: FCM is a firebase service that allows developers to send notifications from cloud. You better use it once.